# Remove citation marks from listoftables in tabular environment

Tags: tables, citing

I use different tabulars environment with titles by using captionof command, most of the tabulars have a citation or footnote mark which appear in my list of tables, how to remove this marks please ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
      \hline 
         Column 1 & Column 2 \\
     \hline
         line     & line     \\
     \hline 
  \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Title\protect\cite{bookmark}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a short title `[Title]` to command `\captionof{table}[Title]{Title\protect\cite{bookmark}}`

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
      \hline 
         Column 1 & Column 2 \\
     \hline
         line     & line     \\
     \hline 
  \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}[Title]{Title\protect\cite{bookmark}} % <==================
%                ^^^^^^^   <================================================
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

gives you:

[image]

The questionmark I get because I do not have your bib file to compile ...